# Lenovo touchpad intermittently freezing

Tags: touchpad, freeze, 22.04

I installed Ubuntu as a dual boot with Windows 11 on a new Lenovo laptop.  Intermittently, the touchpad stops working, and when this happens, usually the keyboard becomes unresponsive as well.  It doesn't unfreeze and I have to hard reboot holding down the power button.

Could anyone please advise one where I can look for further diagnostics besides what I've done below?

**Ubuntu Version**: 22.04 LTS

**Laptop**: Lenovo Legion 5 Pro 16IAH7H - Type 82RF

Extracts from `dmesg`

```
Linux version 5.15.0-37-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-031) (gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #39-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 1 19:16:45 UTC 2022 (Ubuntu 5.15.0-37.39-generic 5.15.35)

DMI: LENOVO 82RF/LNVNB161216, BIOS J2CN40WW 04/15/2022
```

`xinput` gives:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8910) Keyboard  id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:01 06CB:CE78 Mouse               id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:01 06CB:CE78 Touchpad            id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8910) Wireless Radio Control    id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8295) Keyboard  id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8910) Keyboard  id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

And `xinput --list-props 15` gives

```
Device 'MSFT0001:01 06CB:CE78 Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (205):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (207): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (363): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (364): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (365):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (366):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (367):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (368):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (369):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (370):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (342):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (343):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (371):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (372):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (347):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (348):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (349):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (373): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (374):    1, 0
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (375):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (376):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (377):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (354): 0.588235
    libinput Accel Speed Default (355): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (356):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (357):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (358):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (359): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (360): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (327): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (328):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (329):    0, 0
    Device Node (330):  "/dev/input/event5"
    Device Product ID (331):    1739, 52856
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (344):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (345):   1
    libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance (361):    15
    libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance Default (362):    15
    libinput High Resolution Wheel Scroll Enabled (346):    1
```